# How to use main class selection dialog?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want my sbt plugin to have the same behavior as sbt `run` task - use a main class if there's only one and ask a user to choose one if there're multiple. How do I do it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question more?

Comment: `discoveredMainClasses` lists all main classes.

Comment: Do you want exactly dialog like CLI or simple read input will be enough for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `selectMainClass` setting either shows a dialog or uses the value from `mainClass`